# How to move last cursor using while using VS Code multi cursor

Tags: config, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

How to configure VS Code to move the last cursor position?

To to be more precise, here is the example of the feature for Atom editor.

https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor

Please navigate to "Moving the last cursor that has been created" section. Those are the controls that I'm referring to.

Is there any such functionality in VS Code? Or any extension which can enable this?

Comment: Any 2021 update on this?

Answer (score 1):

ALT + Click , now i don't remember on MAC

Comment: I meant something with the keyboard, without having to use trackpad.

Comment: ALT GR + down arrow

Comment: Please go through the question, I meant to move the last cursor position not to create a multi-cursor.